# How do I make highlighted Google Map markers grow?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
function highlightmarker(marker_id) {
    //console.log("Highlight marker id: "+marker_id);
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].id == marker_id) {
            map_markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        }
    }   
}
```

This makes my map markers bounce up and down but I want them to grow instead.

I tried replacing the last line with this but it didn't work:

```
        var img_height = 40; 
        var img_width = 40;
```

How do I make highlighted Google Map markers grow?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Icon (or a MarkerImage that's still supported but deprecated in favor of Icon) and use a the common marker image in it and set the appropriate size/scale you desire, for instance, assuming markers[i] points to a valid marker

`var image = {
  url: " http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png",
  size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
  origin: null,
  anchor: null,
  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
};`

marker[i].setIcon(image);

for a more complete example I created a jsFiddle that sets the icon upon marker creation, http://jsfiddle.net/68gx9/

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
map_markers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

replace marker image with a new bigger one..

```
map_markers[i].setIcon(yourImageUrl);
```